# ibase_query(): Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown

Tags: php, sql, firebird, firebird1.5

I've been trying to do a search filter and this error continue to appear, can someone help me out?

```
{

    require_once('conn.php');

    
    $idata = $_POST["idata"];
    $fdata = $_POST["fdata"];

    $sql = "Select TOP 10* from cadcli where dtcad between $idata and $fdata";
    $query = ibase_query($dbh,$sql) or die (ibase_errmsg());
    while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($query)) {
        echo $row->COLUNA1."n";}
    ibase_free_result($query);
    echo "$query";
    ibase_close($dbh);


}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Firebird doesn't know the keyword `TOP`. The equivalent in Firebird 2.5 and earlier is [`FIRST`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-first-skip). Since Firebird 3, you can also use the SQL standard [`FETCH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-offsetfetch).

Using `FIRST`:

```sql
select first 10 * from cadcli ...
```

Using `FETCH`:

```sql
select * from cadcli ... fetch first 10 rows only
```

Please be aware that without an `ORDER BY`, the order is not deterministic.

I also notice that you are doing string interpolation in your query, which makes it vulnerable to SQL injection. I recommend that you switch to using prepared statements with parameters (see [`ibase_prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-prepare.php) and [`ibase_execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-execute.php)).